# I have a resources (JSON file) which consists of all my required data from the database

Tags: java, android, performance, android-intent, android-activity

I have 3 spinner view one is country,second state ,third distict.when i'm select country then open staes list then select states open dist.

When I'm calling a URL I'm getting a country list. What I'm getting country list to add Spinner view .. it is working fine.. in table=state, I'm not getting state list. How can I call the URL multiple times and send different key parameters.

When I'm selecting country, I call this url: `http://mycompany.com/projects/waap/services/getdynamictables.php`
parameters: keys="table","country"

Getting JSON country data =

```
[{"id":"1","name":"india"},{"id":"2","name":"srilanka"}]
```

I'm choosing India : "table","satate","id" "1"

I want to parse these parameters to the above URL, I'm not getting the state list...

```
states data =[{"id":"1","name":"Ap"},{"id":"2","name":"TM"}]**
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: using code url is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34341962/i-have-3-spinner-view-one-is-country-second-state-third-distict-when-im-select

Comment: May be you are not passing correct parameters. At first confirm with parameters.

Comment: how can i multiple calls to  same url with different parameters .. im trying  to develop registration page  in address get dynamic by using drop down spinners ... sample please...    thanks for replay

Comment: In the spinner, after user selects any item , `onItemSelected()` call the adapter.

Comment: Nigam Patro @ your right...after onItemSelected() im getting position its ok.. how can recall url with different parameters ..help me